# Display Multiple Records From SQL Query Using AJAX with Timer

Tags: php, ajax, timer

I'm trying to find a good example on how to retrieve records using PHP from a table and refresh it say every 2 minutes using Ajax.

Anyone can point me to that tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a tutorial that specific, but you just need to learn [AJAX](http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) and then make the AJAX call every two minutes using JavaScript's [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method.

---

**EDIT**

Meh, I'm bored enough to write this example. This isn't tested, but I don't think it has errors.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            // call your AJAX function every 2 minutes (120000 milliseconds)
            setInterval("getRecords()", 120000);
        };

        function getRecords()
        {
            // create the AJAX variable
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            // set up the response function
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    /*
                        Your code goes here. 'xmlhttp.responseText' has the output from getRecords.php
                    */
                    document.getElementById("txaRecords").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            // make the AJAX call
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getRecords.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txaRecords"></textArea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1034801: There should be a check mark that you can use to select this as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of code that I wrote for this exact purpose. Adapt as appropriate.

AJAX code:

```
function timer()
{
var t=setTimeout("check()",2000);
// At an appropriate interval
}


function check(){

        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText!=""){
                 var output = xmlhttp.responseText;
                 // Do what you need to do with this variable
              }
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","backend.php",true);
          // Set file name as appropriate.
        xmlhttp.send(); 
        timer();
        }
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

// This assumes you have already done mysql_connect() somewhere.

// Replace as appropriate
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

// Perform the query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Get the results in an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Echo the message in an appropriate format.                
    echo "<br />" . $row['column_name'];
}
?>
```

Remember to initiate one of the JS functions as you load the page:

```
<body onload="timer()">
```